# TypeScript: How to read from Firebase Realtime Database inside a triggered function

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

## Background

I have the `nodeACreated` function that triggers on `/Database/nodeA`. Before doing any work on that function when it gets triggered I would like to (preferably immediately) read from `/Database/nodeB` into a variable (`additionalValues`) to use that variable as an argument for `onNodeACreated` later.

I would like to do this sequentially: a write happens in Firebase > function `nodeACreated` gets triggered > read values from `/Database/nodeB` > proceed to running `onNodeACreated` with the values received from reading `/Database/nodeB`

```
export const nodeACreated = firebase.database.ref('/Database/nodeA').onCreate((snapshot) => {

    additionalValues: any [];

    return adm.database().ref('Database/NodeB').once('value').then((snapshot) =>
    {
    additionalValues = snapshot.val();
    return other_module.onNodeACreated(additionalValues);
    });
    });
}
```

other_module:

```
export function onNodeACreated(additionalValues): <any> {
    console.log(`additionalValues`)
}
```

## Problem

Apparently due to my poor understanding [of Promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), I am doing/returning this wrong.

When onNodeACreated runs and I print `additionalValues` to console, it is `undefined`.

## Question

When a triggered function launches how can I read from the other node of Firebase Realtime Database before proceeding with that function?

Comment: Please edit the question to both show exactly where your log line is that printed undefined, and also fix the formatting of the code.  Also, I'll point out that since you're using TypeScript, you also have async/await syntax available, which will make all this a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I have updated the question. Apparently, I should use additionalValues only inside the first function